# installing Mod_Mono and Xsp4 on CentOS 6.3

Tags: mono, centos, mod-mono, xsp

I've gotten Mono 3.0.1 installed, but I'm running into tons of dependency issues trying to install Mod_Mono and Xsp4, Has anyone gotten this to work? If so what were some of the steps you had to take? Is there a central location for this?

Thank you so much for taking the time to read my question and happy coding!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enviroment:
Centos 6.3 basic install
Apache/2.2.15

Installation steps:

```
#Install required software
yum -y install httpd httpd-devel make glib2-devel libpng-devel libjpeg-devel 
giflib-devel libtiff-devel libX11-devel gcc* fontconfig-devel bison gettext bzip2  
libtool automake autoconf wget unzip
```

## directory we will be installing mono in

```
mkdir -p /opt/mono 

cd /tmp
```

## Download & extract source

```
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-2.10.2.tar.bz2
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/xsp/xsp-2.10.2.tar.bz2
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mod_mono/mod_mono-2.10.tar.bz2
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/libgdiplus/libgdiplus-2.10.tar.bz2

tar -xjf mono-2.10.2.tar.bz2
tar -xjf xsp-2.10.2.tar.bz2
tar -xjf mod_mono-2.10.tar.bz2
tar -xjf libgdiplus-2.10.tar.bz2
```

## compile and install libgdiplus

```
cd libgdiplus-2.10
./configure --prefix=/opt/mono
make ; make install
```

## compile and install mono

```
cd ../mono-2.10.2
./configure  --prefix=/opt/mono --with-libgdiplus=/opt/mono
make ; make install
```

## Set enviroment vars(make sure to also modify ~/.bash_profile)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/mono/bin
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/mono/lib/pkgconfig
```

## compile and install xsp

```
cd ../xsp-2.10.2
./configure --prefix=/opt/mono
make ; make install
```

## compile and install mod_mono

```
cd ../mod_mono-2.10
./configure --prefix=/opt/mono --with-mono-prefix=/opt/mono
make ; make install


mv /etc/httpd/conf/mod_mono.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

Comment: why did you add support for libgdiplus ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently working with mono and xsp4:

```
[root]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

[root]# mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.5.0

[root]# xsp4 --version
xsp4.exe 2.10.2.0
```

Chazt3n solution is ok, except I had to do some changes to make it work:

- I changed the mono version from **4.0** to **4.5** in file: **/opt/mono/bin/mod-mono-server4**
- I ran this command: **cp /opt/mono/lib/mono/4.0/xsp4.exe /opt/mono/lib/mono/4.5/**

Works well now, thanks.